# Access Google Cloud data using a service account

Tags: service, oauth, cloud

How to retrieve data from a user's Google Cloud account without using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only` scope, using a Google service account in Google Cloud?

We are able to only my apps data using this scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only`